# How to count the visible items in a specific field of PivotTable without looping?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

How to count the visible items in a specific field of PivotTable without looping through all the items?

The code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("MyFieldName").PivotItems.Count
```

returns the total number of items, no matter if they are selected or not.

I am looking for something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).VisibleSlicerItems.Count
```

Update. I want to count how many items are selected in [Country] field of the picture below:

[image]

(I burglared the picture from: http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/ Hope, Jon won't mind it.)

Comment: I never heared of something like that... to get a count of a specific property having a set value inside of an array, without loop... would be really good to know...

Comment: So, In your given example, the count should return 1, as only UK is selected.

Comment: Yep, but imagine, that multiple items have been chosen.

Comment: Are you aware that if in the sample pivot table more than one country are selected the filter will show "(Multiple Items)", and the number of items actually shown cannot be known just by looking at the pivot table. Bear in mind that even looping through the items will not tell how many of them are actually shown as filters applied to other fields may exclude any of these items if they not comply with the criteria applied to other fields. Again if in sample pivot table we select year 2005 only four months will be shown, but all items of field Order Date will have their visible property as TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but here is a simple solution

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("MyFieldName").VisibleItems.Count
```

I needed this for a report automation project.

Answer (score 1):

This simple macro

```
Sub visible_PivotItemCount()

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"), "1"). _
    Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "Slicer_1", "MySlicer", 1, 1, 1, 1

MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).VisibleSlicerItems.Count)

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1").Delete

End Sub
```

counts the number of selected filters using the VisibleSlicerItems.Count property

Comment: Unfortunately, my items are in in the upper filter of pivot table, so called PageRange. To use your method, I would have to move MyFieldName to column range of pivot table, but that is a bad way to do it. Nevertheless thank you for the direction.

Comment: You want to know how many items are checked in your filter and not to count how many visible rows a filtered query (by MyFieldName) delivers, won't you?

Comment: As far as I know, there is any Property for PivotItems that counts the selected (or unselected) items of a filter. I can imagine, that the field MyFieldName is extremely large. Hence, your reticence to use a loop, although in my tests I get a valid result in less than 20 secs for a field with 10000 elements (and my computer is not the most modern one). You can, however do a little trick with the native function of VisibleSlicerItems (as you already wrote). It consists in creating a new Slicer, count the elements selected and destroying it again. See answer with edited macro.

Comment: No need to create the Slicer as only the SlicerCache is used. Also need to check first if the SlicerCache alreay exist, otherwise it raise an Error. Yet still has the same situation about filters applied to other fields...